# How to manipulate iOS contacts with SwiftAddressBook?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get all the users contacts and see if they are already singed up in the backend. I'm trying first to get all the contacts using [SwiftAddressBook](https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook) and then I want to edit all the phone numbers and add country code to phone number.

I made this function but it doesn't work, it's only showing phone numbers.

```
 SwiftAddressBook.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if success {
                if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                    for person in people {
                        var phonenumber = String (person.phoneNumbers?.map({$0.value}))
                          print(phonenumber.characters.last)
                        if phonenumber.characters.first == "0" {
                           phonenumber = phonenumber.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(phonenumber.startIndex..<phonenumber.startIndex.successor(), withString: "+33")
                        }

                        print(phonenumber)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
              print("Fail")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in first, you should call `swiftAddressBook.save()` to save the current state of the address book. In second, you are changing a local string variable, which will not affect the address book state. It appears `SwiftAddressBook` will only make changes to the contacts if you change `phoneNumbers` array. This should work:

```
SwiftAddressBook.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                for person in people {
                    if let phoneNumbers = person.phoneNumbers {
                        var phoneNumbersChanged = false
                        var newPhoneNumbers = [MultivalueEntry<String>]()

                        for var phonenumber in phoneNumbers {
                            if phonenumber.value.characters.first == "0" {
                                phonenumber.value = phonenumber.value.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(phonenumber.value.startIndex..<phonenumber.value.startIndex.successor(), withString: "+33")
                                newPhoneNumbers.append(MultivalueEntry(value: phonenumber.value, label: phonenumber.label, id: phonenumber.id))
                                phoneNumbersChanged = true
                            } else {
                                newPhoneNumbers.append(phonenumber)
                            }

                            print(phonenumber.value)
                        }

                        if phoneNumbersChanged {
                            person.phoneNumbers = newPhoneNumbers
                        }
                    }
                }
                swiftAddressBook.save()
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Fail")
        }
    })
```